# Как прогрузить всю страницу для парсинга? Пишет только первые 5 задач, нужно чтобы выдало все 48. Заранее очень благодарен

Tags: python, requests, beautiful-soup

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

url = "https://phys-ege.sdamgia.ru/test?theme=204"
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BS(response.content, "html.parser")
data = soup.find_all('div',class_='problem_container')
for i in data:
    v = i.find('p',class_="left_margin")
    print(v.text)
```

Comment: Запустить например DevTools и увидеть что при прокрутке идет POST-запрос с параметрами.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если использовать другую ссылку [Версия для печати и копирования в MS Word](https://phys-ege.sdamgia.ru/test?theme=204&print=true), то выводятся все задания сразу. Можно обойтись без программирования - просто скопировать в Word.
Если же все-таки нужно Python'ом, то нужно еще почистить текст от "мягких переносов" [`&shy;`](https://developer.roman.grinyov.name/blog/81) с кодом 173:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

url = "https://phys-ege.sdamgia.ru/test?theme=204&print=true"
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BS(response.content, "html.parser")
data = soup.find_all('div', class_='pbody')
shy = chr(173)
for i in data:
    v = i.find('p', class_="left_margin")
    print(v.text.replace(shy, ''))
```